# Destructuring bind for regex matches

Tags: emacs, destructuring

In elisp, how can I get a destructuring bind for regex matches?

For example,

```
;; what is the equivalent of this with destructuring?
(with-temp-buffer
  (save-excursion (insert "a b"))
  (re-search-forward "\\(a\\) \\(b\\)")
  (cons (match-string 1)
        (match-string 2)))

;; trying to do something like the following
(with-temp-buffer
  (save-excursion (insert "a b"))
  (cl-destructuring-bind (a b) (re-search-forward "\\(a\\) \\(b\\)")
    (cons a b)))
```

I was thinking I would have to write a macro to expand matches if there isn't another way.

Comment: I don't think that question makes sense. `re-search-forward` itself doesn't return a data structure that's relevant to what you want to do, so I don't see any purpose to trying to use a destructuring bind here. Just stick to your original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way: you first extend `pcase` to accept a new `re-match` pattern, with a definition such as:

```
(pcase-defmacro re-match (re)
  "Matches a string if that string matches RE.
RE should be a regular expression (a string).
It can use the special syntax \\(?VAR: to bind a sub-match
to variable VAR.  All other subgroups will be treated as shy.

Multiple uses of this macro in a single `pcase' are not optimized
together, so don't expect lex-like performance.  But in order for
such optimization to be possible in some distant future, back-references
are not supported."
  (let ((start 0)
        (last 0)
        (new-re '())
        (vars '())
        (gn 0))
    (while (string-match "\\\\(\\(?:\\?\\([-[:alnum:]]*\\):\\)?" re start)
      (setq start (match-end 0))
      (let ((beg (match-beginning 0))
            (name (match-string 1 re)))
        ;; Skip false positives, either backslash-escaped or within [...].
        (when (subregexp-context-p re start last)          
          (cond
           ((null name)
            (push (concat (substring re last beg) "\\(?:") new-re))
           ((string-match "\\`[0-9]" name)
            (error "Variable can't start with a digit: %S" name))
           (t
            (let* ((var (intern name))
                   (id (cdr (assq var vars))))
              (unless id
                (setq gn (1+ gn))
                (setq id gn)
                (push (cons var gn) vars))
              (push (concat (substring re last beg) (format "\\(?%d:" id))
                    new-re))))
          (setq last start))))
    (push (substring re last) new-re)
    (setq new-re (mapconcat #'identity (nreverse new-re) ""))
    `(and (pred stringp)
          (app (lambda (s)
                 (save-match-data
                   (when (string-match ,new-re s)
                     (vector ,@(mapcar (lambda (x) `(match-string ,(cdr x) s))
                                       vars)))))
               (,'\` [,@(mapcar (lambda (x) (list '\, (car x))) vars)])))))
```

and once that is done, you can use it as follows:

```
(pcase X
  ((re-match "\\(?var:[[:alpha:]]*\\)=\\(?val:.*\\)")
   (cons var val)))
```

or

```
(pcase-let
    (((re-match "\\(?var:[[:alpha:]]*\\)=\\(?val:.*\\)") X))
  (cons var val))
```

This has not been heavily tested, and as mentioned in the docstring it doesn't work as efficiently as it (c|sh)ould when matching a string against various regexps at the same time.  Also you only get the matched substrings, not their position.  And finally, it applies the regexp search to a string, whereas in manny/most cases regexps searches are used in a buffer.  But you may still find it useful.